# Box Rest API V2

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to bring Box API to my iOS app. I see there are 2 versions of Box API. The version 1 is deprecated and will sunset at December 14, 2013. But I could not found where I can download full source code of API version 2, I want to customize the API for my iOS app, not using static library. Does anyone know where I can download API version 2 source code for Box ?

Thanks,

Comment: Since Box is a commercial service, I don't think they release the source of their client library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source for the v2 iOS SDK is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2).